# Install changes for config files as an update and remove it neatly if not needed

Tags: debian, config, updates, package-managers, installation-package

**Background:**

I have configured my Raspberry Pi to work as a wireless access point. To do that I had to edit multiple daemon config files and delete some packages altogether. Now I want to automate this process: I want to create software, let's say an update package, that automatically updates any Raspberry Pi to this configuration. And I want to be able to reverse this process - like uninstalling, but all the deleted daemons and the edited config files return to their original status.

**Question:**

Is there a built in system that I can use to accomplish this? I thought about using the debian package manager, yet I'm unsure whether I can use it to the extent that I described above (deleting / changing other software?) And will I be able to reverse the installation completely?

Comment: This is probably more suitable for [unix.se]

Comment: Some people have successfully created config packages which can be installed and uninstalled with Apt / `dpkg`. See e.g. https://debathena.mit.edu/config-packages/